# Node.js Redis lpush error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I'm making a web app using node.js and redis.
I want to push every incoming request into a redis queue before pushing it to a database.
But every time the program reaches the lpush command it gives an error.
Here is my index.js code,

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var qs=require('querystring');
var redis=require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var count=0;
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
//var countm=1;
//var counte=1;

app.get('/adminm', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('adminmovies.html');
});

app.get('/admine', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('adminevents.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res){
    count=count+1;
    var body="";
    req.on('data',function(data){
    body+=data;
    });
    req.on('end',function(){
    console.log(body);
    var xml=body;
    var parsed="";
    parseString(xml, function(err,result){
        console.dir(result);
        parsed=result;
    });
    //var post=qs.parse(body);
    io.emit('count1',count);
    redis.lpush('events',parsed);
    //console.log(post);

    });


});

/*io.on('connection',function(socket){

});*/


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And the error is,

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/Desktop/express-app/index.js:37:8)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:902:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:11)
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the redis client but not using it anywhere.

In line 37 you're calling `lpush` directly on imported module:

```
 redis.lpush('events',parsed);
```

where `lpush` is undefined.